# Issue with /wait command in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

Am trying to uninstall one application and after uninstallation I want to clean up some folders. This is the command I used to uninstall.

```
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
 start /wait /d "%folder%"\test setup.exe
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (ftp.txt) DO (
  if %errorlevel% == 0 (call :skip)
 )

 :skip
 rd /s /q "%location%"
 rd /s /q "%folder%"\agent
)
```

Here my question is , **even I cancel the uninstallation still its removing the folders.**

Can anyone suggest me where am doing wrong.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

First problem: a label within a block `(a parenthesised series of statements)` terminates the block (this may be version-dependent) Hence, the commands following the label will be executed regardless of what the result of the remainder of the block is.

Second problem: the routine `:skip` is terminated by an unbalanced `)`. This may be harmless in itself, but it does **not** terminate the routine. `call :skip` will continue to an `exit` or end-of-file before returning.

Third problem: Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

So - in your case, the second `if %errorlevel% == 0` will applt the value of `errorlevel` at the time the very first `if` in the snippet you show us was encountered, **not** the changed value depending on the processing.

Next problem is that you are excuting the `for/f` on `ftp.txt` and appear to do nothing with the data gathered from `ftp.txt` - `%%a` is not used at all in the routine, all it does is attempt to `call :skip` once for each line in `ftp.txt`.

So-

```
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
 start /wait /d "%folder%"\test setup.exe
 if not errorlevel 1 (call :skip)
)
goto :eof    


:skip
rd /s /q "%location%"
rd /s /q "%folder%"\agent
goto :eof
```

may do the job, assuming that `errorlevel` is set to non-zero if the uninstallation is cancelled. Note that the format `if [not] errorlevel n` applies to the **run-time** value of errorlevel whereas `if %errorlevel% == 0` applies to the **parse-time** value.

Without knowledge of what `ftp.txt` and `%%a` are supposed to be used for, I've no idea what to do with them...

Answer (score 0):

try this edit:

```
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
start /wait /d "%folder%"\test setup.exe
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (ftp.txt) DO (
if %errorlevel% == 0 (call :skip) )
goto done
:skip
rd /s /q "%location%"
rd /s /q "%folder%"\agent ) 
:done
```

Comment: ok, so.... what exactly is the purpose of the for loop? you already know errorlevel is 0 if you are running the loop, and all it does is check that.... so what does it accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you - If `setup.exe` returns a `non-zero` errorlevel then it will skip the folder removals.

```
  start "Title" /wait /d "%folder%\test" setup.exe
  if not errorlevel 1 (
    rd /s /q "%location%"
    rd /s /q "%folder%\agent"
  )
```